# How do I find the largest files and folders on a drive?

Tags: windows-xp, software-rec, file-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

I am looking for a tool to tell me which files and folders are the largest as I need to do some cleanup.

Comment: related to (but different from) http://superuser.com/questions/9847/linux-utility-for-finding-the-largest-files-directories

Comment: Good question I have wondering to search it out too!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Check out [Treesize](http://www.jamsoft.net/treesize_free/). It's an awesome app that shows you the sizes of all the files/folders on your machine.

[image]

Comment: It should be noted that there is both a free and paid version. The free version does not access Network drives. So keep that in mind.

Comment: TreeSize helped me to find a hidden system folder for a backup utility that came bundled with my desktop.  Unfortunately, I had removed the program and never new about the file it had already created!  

After I got suspicious about the dearth of unused space on this desktop's hard drive I fired up TreeSize and discovered the hidden folder - it didn't show up in Windows Exploer even with hidden folders turned on.  Tree size let me remove the folder.

Comment: Simple, intuitive, lightweight, love it!

Comment: Really usable app. Developer obviously eats their own dog food. For example, if you expand a folder that only contains another folder, it will expand the child folder too.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this is a simple, quick, intuitive tool.

Comment: Works as expected on Win7 also

Answer (score 79):

[WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info) is great for finding large files on your drive, it's also easy to find if you have many files of a specific file type that takes a lot of space.

[image]

Comment: +1 For some reason I like this tool too. Despite the graphical area representation being nothing more than a curiosity, it really appeals to me. Even more strange because I'm usually not very keen on graphical-oriented applications :)

Comment: the graphics are nice but they are not labled so they are kinda pointless.

Comment: I like it too, mouseover (or is it click?) the pretty colored blocks and it shows them in the text area above. I use the portable one linked below.

Comment: SpaceSniffer uses a similar display but is rather more useful as it labels what each area represents.

Comment: @tvanover: not pointless. when you click an area in the graphic part it shows you the path in the top listing part, and when you click in the listing it shows the outline in the graphics part. It's remarkably useful.

Comment: @tvanover .. in addition the graphical section is colour coded as per the top right section of the program

Comment: `choco install windirstat`

Answer (score 14):

[WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) - displays a graphical view and list of files and directories, by size.  There's a portable version at [PortableApps.com](http://portableapps.com/) if you don't want to install it.

Comment: duplicate of the other answer

Comment: Actually, salle55's is a duplicate of mine -- this was posted first by six minutes (check the timestamps). The other one has, however, received more votes, presumably because of the picture.

Comment: +1 for portal app

Answer (score 4):

Nothing better than [Folder Size](http://foldersize.sourceforge.net/). It actually adds a column to your view.

Comment: +1 Too bad it doesn't work in Vista and Seven. I miss this app terribly.

Answer (score 4):

I use the old [Space Monger](http://www.sixty-five.cc/sm/v1x.php).  It is pretty basic visual representation of your dive contents.  Along the line of WinDirStat it shows the space taken up by a folder or file's contents.!.  I like it over WinDirStat because it labels the shapes so you can see very quickly what folders and files take up the most space.  It is a bit slow to index when you first open, but reloading after changes, even on my terabyte network shares is almost instantaneous.

[image: Space Monger 1.4.0 screenshot]

The interface is simple and to the point, with no extraneous gimmicks.  Also there is no install all you need is the exe and you are good to go.

Comment: SpaceSniffer is a better looking version of this

Answer (score 2):

[**OverDisk**](http://users.forthnet.gr/pat/efotinis/programs/overdisk.html) works great (although it's a version 0.11 beta). The "pie" view is great to identify the biggest directories and files.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use [Better Directory Analyzer](http://download.cnet.com/Better-Directory-Analyzer/3000-2248_4-75912643.html). It's free, powerful and has some nice visualization options.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

my favorite is spacemonger.  1.40 is still free.  gives you a nice, colorful graphical view of what's on your drive by size.

Answer (score 1):

I always seem to have a few examples of this type of software installed. Here's what's on my laptop at the moment...

**[DriveSpacio](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Hard-Disk-Utils/DriveSpacio.shtml)**
My favourite. Simple and effective, available with a right click in the context menu and displays nice, clear bar charts.

**[File size chart](http://www.primitivezone.com/primitive-file-size-chart.html)** Another simple one but not as good as DriveSpacio.

**[SpaceSniffer](http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/index.html)** I'm very visual but the way this displays the space baffles me (it's a bit like WinDirStat). Fun watching it 'grow' though.

[**FolderSize**](http://foldersize.codeplex.com/) is a new one (found via [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5386811/foldersize-displays-whats-eating-your-hard-drive-space)). Short on functions at the moment but with a new and useful way to represent the space taken.

Answer (score 1):

I use foldersize in Windows XP ( http://foldersize.sourceforge.net ).

It replaces the "size" column in Windows explorer with a similar column that shows the size of folders as well as files. once you  have used it,  the normal view  with a space for the size of a folder just looks wrong.

Because it is always there, I find that I tend not to let folders get quite so messy before sorting them out - with a separate program I have to decide to have a tidy up rather than keep on top of the cleaning.

Answer (score 1):

For viewing disk usage I prefer Steffen Gerlach's [Scanner](http://www.steffengerlach.de/freeware/), for its innovative and visual pie display, and where each pie can be accessed by using the right-click.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[JDiskReport](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jdiskreport/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) so here is what you can do:

- from **Show** select **Full**
- in Header sort files by **Size**
- hit [Alt]+[Shift]+[Enter] to show folder sizes

simple as that, the biggest folder is up and the smaller down (the list)

Answer (score 1):

TreePie

[image]

http://sourceforge.net/projects/treepie/

TreePie shows a single piechart for your drive, so you can quickly see where the big chunks are, and if there are big chunks within those chunks you can focus on.  You can select any chunk with your mouse to see detailed information.

Comment: some explaination to what are the strengths and weaknessess of the solution would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Go for [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/). This is a search utility, but sorting this on size can give result very fast.

> - Small installation file
> - Clean and simple user interface
> - Quick file indexing
> - Quick searching
> - Minimal resource usage
> - Share files with others easily
> - Real-time updating
> - More...

Comment: Nice use of a great tool. How long does it take for, say, a 100GB drive?

Answer (score 0):

I find [FilePro](http://www.saleensoftware.com/FilePro.aspx) to be best for me. Fast (really), small, clear interface, different views available. Best I ever had.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you can use [Baobab](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeUtils/Baobab), or a oneliner like this:

```
find . -type f -exec ls -l {} \; | cut -d' ' -f 5,10 | sort -n | tail
```

This will give you the 10 largest files (largest in the bottom), remove `| tail` for the whole list