# How to write a batch file to delete subfolders less then 10MB?

Tags: windows, batch

I have a folder, `"myFolder"`. In `"myFolder"`, I have many subfolders.

I know that if the subfolder is less than 10MB, it can be deleted.

Instead of checking the folder step by step, how can I write a batch job to help me delete just the folders?

Comment: Yes, but surely you wish to delete files *inside* the folders as well. For all folders, by themselves, are smaller than 10mb.

Comment: yes, I mean....in "myFolder", there have many sub folders , and files. ONLY the files in the sub folders can be deleted. outside the sub folder, and inside the myFolder that can not be deleted. thz.

Comment: This is really a message which belongs at stack overflow.  The closest I could find was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759481/batch-file-to-display-directory-size which at least gives you the directory size but has to scan each folder which is incredibly slow.  

You should use a scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-time operation, any tool that shows you the sizes of your subfolders will do.

The post [How do I find the largest files and folders on a drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/57414/how-do-i-find-the-largest-files-and-folders-on-a-drive/124810#124810) gives you many tools (and more tools [in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)).