# how to tell whats eating my harddrive space?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-space

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Best free tool to find largest files and folders on a drive](https://superuser.com/questions/57414/best-free-tool-to-find-largest-files-and-folders-on-a-drive)
>   [Best program to visualize file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/best-program-to-visualize-file-system-usage-on-windows)

does anyone know a free software that will graph the directories on my hard drive and sort them in order of largest size?

or provide me a solution for me to quickly determine what drives/ files are consuming my hard drive space?

Comment: What OS?  You need to provide more information

Comment: This question would be better suited for SU

Comment: Oh, I found another one: http://superuser.com/questions/8248/best-program-to-visualize-file-system-usage-on-windows

Comment: @Bobby So how do you know the user is on Windows?

Comment: @Daniel Beck: Good point...was a wild guess, a Linux/MacOSX/anyOtherOsUser would have, most likely, mentioned it.

Comment: Seeing which folder is the biggest doesn't really help, though.  I cleared 11 GB a few days ago and now I have 3 free.  I need to know which folders are getting hugely bigger over time, not just which ones are hugely big.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had really good luck with [windirstat](http://windirstat.info/), if you're on Windows of course.

Answer (score 8):

You can use utilities such as [KDirStat](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/) (Linux/KDE) to visualize where your free space went.

[image]

---

[WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) is a similar tool for Windows.

[image]

---

[Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/) is for Mac OS X.

[image]

Comment: Very succinct answer and I like the screenshots.  I've used gt5 on linux in the past but I'm going to give kdirstat a try.

Answer (score 0):

For windows- have a look at [getfoldersize](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/getfoldersize.html) - it doesn't graph but it does sort by usage and allows you to drill down and find high usage sub directories etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a *nix environment it's quick to just use `du -sh /dir` to find offensively sized directories. It's somewhat crude, but quick and effective.