# Windows 7: application to check folder size in computer

Tags: windows-7, windows, disk-space

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Reclaiming disk space on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/8141/reclaiming-disk-space-on-windows)
>   [Best free tool to find largest files and folders on a drive](https://superuser.com/questions/57414/best-free-tool-to-find-largest-files-and-folders-on-a-drive)

I would like check my computer's C: drive for files that consume an lot of space. What would be the best application to do this? On Mac I have used [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/) for this purpose, is there a similar freeware program available for Windows 7?

Comment: And, as per the answer below: [Best free tool to find largest files and folders on a drive](http://superuser.com/questions/57414/best-free-tool-to-find-largest-files-and-folders-on-a-drive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will tell you the size. You can check sizes in kb,mb and gb with detailed sub-folder display.
FolderSize
http://www.mindgems.com/products/Folder-Size/Folder-Size.html
and this SuperUser answer
[How do I find the largest files and folders on a drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/57414/best-free-tool-to-find-largest-files-and-folders-on-a-drive)