# Constantly running out of space with nothing installed

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-space

I'm running out of space on C:.

Problem is I have deleted EVERYTHING. I don't understand where the space has gone. It's like it doesn't "regenerate" when I delete files. I've uninstalled Visual Studio and as I was uninstalling it, I saw a 6Gb decrease.

After a reboot I'm down to 200 Mb. Help!

Comment: How big is your hard driver in GB?

Comment: Can I assume you have emptied your recycle bin?

Comment: I did empty it. The disk is 55 Gb (it's an SSD)

Comment: Switch to administrator mode and see if there are files you're not seeing from your standard signon.

Comment: do a [disk clean](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-imagefileviewer/CommunityServer-Blogs-Components-WeblogFiles-00-00-01-07-80/3125.Disk-Cleanup.png_2D00_550x0.png) up and make sure all the temp files are gone

Answer (score 0):

Check these folders for build up.

```
C:\Users\_Your_username_\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5
“C:\Users\_Your_username_\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application”
“C:\Users\_Your_username_\AppData\Local\Chromium\Application”
“C:\Users\_Your_username_\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Media Player”
“C:\Users\_Your_username_\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Media Player\Image cache”
“C:\Users\_Your_username_\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Messenger”
“C:\Users\_Your_username_\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Live\Contacts”
“C:\Users\_Your_username_\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Live\Contacts\your_email@live.com\15.4\DBStore\Backup\new”
“C:\Users\_Your_username_\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Speech\Files\MSASR”
“C:\Users\_Your_username_\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Speech\Files\TrainingAudio”
“C:\Users\_Your_username_\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer”
“C:\Users\_Your_username_\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Burn\”
“C:\Users\_Your_username_\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Photo Gallery\Original Images”
“C:\Users\_Your_username_\AppData\Local\Temp”
c:\windows\temp
c:\program files\NVIDIA Corporation\Installer2

fsutil usn deletejournal /D C:
chkdsk /f c:
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [disk space management tool](https://superuser.com/questions/57414/how-do-i-find-the-largest-files-and-folders-on-a-drive) to find out which folders occupy most of your disk space. Make sure to run them "**As Administrator**" so that these tools are able to see the whole content of your disk.

If you are not sure what recently ate up your disk space, use the print feature to get a printed report, you can use this later to compare it with your current results.

Even after emptying the recycle bin, the folder **Windows System Restore** may still eat up some of the disk space as it uses NTFS shadow copies to be able to restore previous states of the hard disk and the system configuration. Windows will free this space automatically after some time as it deletes old system restore point from time to time. You can manually delete system restore points in the “System” applet of the Windows Control Panel.