# Virus hides files, shrinks total capacity

Tags: hard-drive, virus, disk-space, window

A virus infected my hard drive.

The drive's capacity is 1 TB and has different type of files on it, 400 GB+ in total. Suddenly all the files disappear, and I tried to show hidden files, but it only shows the autorun and a shortcut (probably virus). Its total capacity became 500 GB from 1 TB and the space occupied is 1 GB-, so I'm pretty confident that my files are hidden somewhere.

Just to be clear:

Before: 400 GB+ (space occupied) / 900 GB+ (total space)

Now: 800 MB+ (space occupied) / 563 GB (total space)

Screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Have you ran an AV scan? Did you have anti-virus software to begin with?

Comment: yeah scanned the hdd and deleted the virus, even moved the drive to different computer as a slave but still no show

Comment: [All My Files and Folders are Hidden after Rogue Virus attack](http://www.pchell.com/support/unhidefiles.shtml)

Comment: tried to show hidden files but it only shows the autorun and bootsqm.dat and shows that there is no space occupied

Comment: not sure with the exact size range but im definite that if you deduct my files in the hdd which are now missing, youll get its present capacity which is shrinked

Comment: Post a screenshot of your Windows Disk Management screen.

Comment: screenshot posted

Comment: Have you checked volume shadow storage, and the size of ‪C:\System Volume Information? You'll need to give yourself permissions on ‪System Volume Information before you can enumerate its size and contents.

Comment: im referring to drive E by the way, system volume information's file size in E is 2.89mb, how to check volume shadow storage?

Comment: Hi Kelvin, 

have you tried using WinDirStat to see exactly where your space is going?

It may not be able to show you the files if the're hidden but should still show you the directory.

https://windirstat.info/download.html

Comment: Option: If you can plug this hard disk to a linux based operating system or have a linux based operating system on a  different partition, easily you can find all the files that are missing.

Comment: @KelvinBarsana Maybe you could use something like [MiniTool Partition Wizard](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) to check for any hidden/lost partitions and recover them. For the first part of your question, **Michał Sacharewicz**'s answer seems to be on point.

Comment: The name of the virus would be relevant here to give any informed answer, otherwise there's just wild guesses.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to recover the disk to former state, that is, to recover the directory structure of the dive without transfering the data to another disk and then retransfering it to the drive. But I can tell you how to see the files in the drive that are hidden(by viruses).
Open the drive, type `*.*` into the search field, this will show all the files and folders in that drive. I think this will do the trick because this happens to me often with virus infected drives and I find the files in it by this way.
**Note:** *I am not sure whether this will work or not in your case because there is also a problem of reduced capacity with the drive.*

Comment: Answer is much improved.

Comment: sorry, but it still doesn't show my files

Comment: Please attach a screenshot of TreeSize Professional to this post or to a support request at JAM Software.

Comment: @RogUE have tried it on linux and even its testdisk software but still no light

Answer (score 1):

Use a [disk space management tool](https://superuser.com/questions/57414/how-do-i-find-the-largest-files-and-folders-on-a-drive) to find out which folders occupy most or an unusual amount of your disk space. Make sure to run them "**As Administrator**" so that these tools are able to see the whole content of your disk.

There are two features of my tool [TreeSize Professional](http://www.jam-software.de/treesize/) (fully functional 30 day trial available without registration) which might help in this situation:

- You can [compare a previous state with a current state](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize/xml-reports_and_snapshots.shtml)
- When run "as administrator" TreeSize will scan the Master File Table (MFT) of NTFS drives which makes it more difficult for malicious files to hide.

Comment: sorry, but it still doesn't show my files

Answer (score 1):

Your files have been most likely hidden.

There was a popular virus some time ago that changed the file attributes to "hidden" and "system" (`+hs`).

When both those attributes are active, you **cannot unhide the file via Windows GUI**. The only alternative is to use command line and use the `attrib` command. You can check the manual for `attrib` command by typing `attrib -h` and clicking enter.

Please launch the command line using `Ctrl+R` and then typing `cmd` and pressing `Run`.

Basically, from that point you have two alternatives:

- You can manually "unhide" selected files, specifying the path and filenames to the command. This may take really long time.
- You can "unhide" whole `E:` drive at once using `attrib -h -s E:\* /s /d`. This command removes all "hidden" and "system" flags from your files, thus restoring them to life.

If the `E:` drive is not the system drive (ie. the drive that contains Windows), the second option will be a perfectly safe operation.

Comment: -1. The disk itself is shown as smaller. Hiding files does not reduce disk capacity.

Answer (score 1):

There might be two steps of possible solutions:

First, find the list of hidden files in your desired drive by the following command.

Open a command prompt and change the directory to the **root** of your drive. Then run:

```
dir /s /a:h C:*.* > test.txt
```

**Explanation**:

> dir: directory 
>   
>   s: show

This will list all your hidden files in your drive and listed at test.text.

Now open the files through copy pasting the directory in your explorer.

The second possible solution would be opening the recycler:

- Navigate to your drive.
- Click on *Organize* --> *Folder Options*
- Navigate to **view**
- Choose *Show hidden files and folders* and also uncheck the **Hide protected operating system files**
- Click *Apply* and *OK*

Now you will find a drive with a folder named **$recycle.bin**. Open it and view for your hidden files.

Comment: The disk itself is shown as smaller. Hiding files does not reduce disk capacity.

Answer (score 1):

Disk Management shows disk 0 as 931.5 GB, but E: has only 564 GB.

This could have been caused by a weird virus, but also by a problem with the
firmware of the disk.

I would suggest the following :

1. Use a disk-backup product to backup the physical disk 0, sector-by-sector.
   You will need 1 TB of available disk-space on another disk.
   Check that the size of the backup is really 1 TB before continuing.
2. Deep-scan your computer for viruses using several well-known anti-virus
   products. You can use an online scan instead of installing them
   (requires Internet Explorer or Java), for example:
   [Bitdefender](http://www.bitdefender.com/scanner/online/free.html), [ESET](http://www.eset.com/us/online-scanner/), [F‑Secure](https://www.f-secure.com/en/web/home_global/online-scanner).
   Scan only the system disk, and especially do not scan E..
3. In Disk Management, right-click disk 0 and delete the volume, then recreate
   a volume and partition that span the whole disk.

The above procedure is risky and can cost you the contents of the disk,
and also the backup in step 1 above is not guaranteed to succeed.
If you have important data on the disk and no backup, use
a commercial disk recovery service (not cheap) and next time keep a backup disk.

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference between 400GB and 800MB. It's my understanding that all files, not matter the attribute, are accounted for in the disk space chart, which means your hard drive has had the data erased. Have you tried using a recovery tool such as [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva) to recover the files? If you want to try it, make sure nothing is written to the drive, and if recovery is possible make sure that you opt to recover to a drive other than the one you are recovering files fro.

Answer (score 1):

Command prompt

```
attrib -h -r -s /s /d H:\\*.\*
```

Replace the `H` in `H:\\*.\*` with your drive letter)

I didn't know [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hfv/) existed until now.

Comment: i also tried the above command and didn't work, my files are not hidden in that kind of way

Answer (score 0):

Try using cmd. Go to the directory that your files are hidden in and then hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and right click after that click on the open command window here. Then enter these:

```
attrib *. -h -s /s /d
```

Tell me the results. The command will show all of the hidden files including the system files. It doesn't change their system files; it just shows them which you can hidden them after.

Comment: attrib *. -h -s /s /d

Comment: It is not polite to tell people to run commands that will significantly change their file system, without explaining what the commands do. Many people would not want to randomly remove the hidden and system file attribute from significant numbers of files.

Comment: well if a virus is hiding your file then it is very likely that after deleting the virus your files are still hidden.one way to show these files is using cmd. the command will show all of the hidden file including the system files.it doesn't change their system  files it just shows them which you can hidden them after.

Comment: short version: nothing bad happens to your files or system

Comment: @vaasmontenegro - Do yourself a favor.  Modify the answer so you fully explain what the command does.

Comment: now  do your self a favor give my answer a +1

Comment: @vaasmontenegro - Answer is much improved.  An answer that requests additional feedback from the author of the question isn't going to recieve an upvote though.

Comment: sorry, but it still doesn't show my files

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the same problem using this command:

```
chkdsk /x e:
```