# Windows 10 45Gb space was missing

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, disk-space

This is latest, happened two days back on 07-07-2020. I have been using windows for year and I have installed and uninstalled a lot of software in between. My disk space in C:\ drive is 250 GB and it had 43GB of disk space. I have empty =  temp folder, restore points, disk space, system files and windows_old_upadate_backup.

After clearing the files, I could only gain 7GBs which was in total 50GB but recently I updated "windows with latest feature" and after update I gained ******* about 35GB space in C:\ drive. What the hell was taking 35Gb space in my windows.

Not just that everyday my storage space is getting reduced. It was about 73GB yesterday today is 68GB I cleared all the setting and temps but I could only gain 1GB of space.

I don't know what is going on. How can I stop this ?

Any solution ?

Comment: As I mentioned, I didn't clean up the system AFTER the feature update. It did by itself.

Comment: There are various tools for checking used disk space. These won't tell you specifically what used you space, but they can point out things using a lot of space and that information could help you identify the culprit. Otherwise, we cannot tell you what used up space on your drive.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/57414/how-do-i-find-the-largest-files-and-folders-on-a-drive personally I like WizTree