# Bash command for finding file extensions with largest size

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems, disk-space, file-extension

I am trying to find file extensions with sorted by size in a directory and sub directory.

Something like this:

```
 76K    .pek  ./Adobe Premiere Pro Preview Files/demo.PRV/1d860051-77c9-4acb-973e-3b6b4428c54e+57631ed274ffb879a432291c 48000.pek
 18M    .cfa  ./Adobe Premiere Pro Preview Files/demo.PRV/1d860051-77c9-4acb-973e-3b6b4428c54e+57631ed274ffb879a432291c 48000.cfa
 19M          ./.git/objects/e6/66dcd00fc197154f89563f2f1aa508e2ab3b50
 21M    .mov  ./Demo 2.mov
```

and also if possible search excluding some directories like `.git`

I have tried this https://superuser.com/a/397662

Answer (score 1):

The find command on my system works like this

```
 # find . -type f -ls 
... 
145890044    12192 -rw-rw-r--   1 USER GROUP        239234 Jun  7 15:03 ./QA/Audits/scripts/MYFILE.pdf 
...
```

`find . -type f` finds all the files in the current directory and sub directories

`-ls` lists the files

If you wish to exclude directories you can use the prune switch https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489277/how-to-use-prune-option-of-find-in-sh

The size is in column number 7 of the output. So if I want to sort the results, I do this

```
# find . -type f -ls | sort -nr -k7
```

`-n` number
`-r` reverse order (optional)
`-k7` column number 7

Answer (score 0):

I can find the file size

```
$ find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 du | sort -rn | head -10 | cut -f2 | xargs -I{} du -sh {}

  346M   ./Downloads/The Walking Dead S02E02 ... (dutch subs nl).avi
  159M   ./.local/share/Trash/files/funky chicken.mpg
  117M   ./Calibre Library/Robert Martin/cc.mobi
  114M   ./Dropbox/snapshots/monthly.tgz
  114M   ./Dropbox/snapshots/daily.tgz
  114M   ./Dropbox/snapshots/weekly.tgz
  76M    ./tmp/projects/onthisday/onthisday.tar.gz
  76M    ./snapshots/projects/weekly.3/onthisday/onthisday.tar.gz
  76M    ./snapshots/projects/weekly.2/onthisday/onthisday.tar.gz
  76M    ./snapshots/projects/weekly.1/onthisday/onthisday.tar.gz
```

and extensions count

```
$ find . -type f -name "*.*" | grep -o -E "\.[^\.]+$" | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn

 353 .JPG
  53 .png
  45 .mov
  33 .DS_Store
  15 .prproj
     ...
   2 .MXF
   1 .xmp
   1 .psd
   1 .mp4
   1 .md
   1 .m4a
   1 .gitignore
   1 .gitattributes
```

How to combine both, to get `count` `max file size` `extensions`?

Comment: *.* will match things such as my.test.file.txt with the extension "test.file.txt"

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head:

```
du -h --exclude=".git" <starting directory> | sort -h | grep -o "\.[:alnum:]+$"
```

Comment: Answers are intended to be definitive.  If you are sure this will solve the problem, consider leaving off the comment that casts doubt.  If you aren't sure, then posting this as an answer is premature.  Also, can you expand your answer to explain what this does?  Thanks.