# Locate the process hogging my disk space

Tags: linux, disk-space, vmware-player

Guest OS: Windows 10 running on VMware Player.
Host OS: Ubuntu 14.04
Guest OS Disk: 20 GB used of 60 available. Dynamically allocated, single file.

Initial SSD available space: 160 GB.

I'm running a network simulation that consists of hundreds of processes executing on the host OS and communicating with a single process running on the guest machine. None of them write to disk, however, after a few days my 250 GB SSD fills up and the VM is paused automatically.

The strange thing is that when I reboot the host OS the space is available once more.

How can I find the culprit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux utility for finding the largest files/directories](http://superuser.com/questions/9847/linux-utility-for-finding-the-largest-files-directories)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, so I thought it had something to do with the VM but it was actually the terminal's history. I had it set to infinite scrollback so after a few days the debugging messages made up 140 GB of garbage.