# Mounted /home on a partition and GParted shows as if it isn't

Tags: linux, gparted, migration

I have 1 SSD (128 GB) and 1 HDD (1000 GB)

Yesterday, I used this tutorial to migrate my `/home` directory to a different partition

[LINK]:

```
            help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving
```

(followed all steps, less 'Moving /home into /old_home' and 'Deleting the old Home' which they seemed irrelevant for me)

I want `/` and its content (less home) to be stored on the SSD (`sda`) and
`/home` inside the HDD (`sdb`)

So this is my `df` by the moment:

```
 $ df -H | grep /dev/

    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

    /dev/sda1       269M   81M  188M  31% /boot/efi
    /dev/sdb1       242G  205G   26G  90% /
    /dev/sdb2       312G  117G  180G  40% /home
```

I'm about to move the `/` dir to `sda` but this happened:

[GParted on HDD(sdb)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENzFa.png)

`/` seems like has `/home` inside

The contradictory part is that nautilus and `baobab` (or disk usage analyzer) shows `/` size to approximately 15.6 GB.

[root directory properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ARkn.png)

Not letting me copy/paste the `/` partition tho SDD(`sda`) (remember SDD has 128 GB)

Please see these links (Disk Usage Analyzer reports)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally!! This was a bit hard for me
What I did is:
Press ctrl+H on the `/` directory and " .Trash-0"  will appear. So frustating!

I realized this when I used commands to display largest files or dirs. These are shown in this Question [Linux utility for finding the largest files/directories](https://superuser.com/questions/9847/linux-utility-for-finding-the-largest-files-directories)

Just rests `rm -rf ./.Trash-0` and that's it